# Access another series row's data on Highchart dataLabels

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I want to access another series row data in series dataLabels. Here is my code.

```
categoriesarr = [1,2,3,4,5];
noofloandisbursed = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
pdo = [9, 18, 27, 40, 49];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'disbursement'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categoriesarr
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 0,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#fff'),
                shadow: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'No. Of Loan Disbursed',
                type: 'column',
                data: noofloandisbursed
            },
            {
                name: 'Pre-Disbursement Orientation',
                type: 'column',
                data: pdo,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function(e) {
                        //return ((this.point.y/series[0].point.y)*100) + '%';
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
```

I want to show the result of (series 2 value / series 1 value) * 100 in the dataLabels concatenation with % only in second series. Unfortunately i can't access the series 1's y point values. When i tried `series[0].yData`, it returns the whole array, not the specific row matched with second row. I also tried to pass array, but it wasn't working. Need solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the point from the first series by `index`:

```
series: [{
        ...
    },
    {
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function(e) {
                return (
                    (this.point.y /
                        this.series.chart.series[0].points[this.point.index].y) *
                    100) + '%';
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rdwxc382/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.formatter